# Is it good practice to remove redundant plugins and themes?

Tags: plugins, themes, maintenance

Is it good practice to remove all of the plugins and themes that are redundant? Also, if so, why is it good practise to remove them?

Comment: To add to Mark's answer, often a plugin developer releases an update when a security hole has been found and fixed. If you don't update or remove these plugins, hackers will try and exploit this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Always remove any code you do not use which is easy to remove, like unused plugins and themes. Too many times even an unused code proved to be a vector through which sites were hacked.

Comment: Time to delete all those harmful inactive twenty-something themes. ;-)

Comment: @Mark Kaplun, may I ask you to have a look at a custom field related question here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265852/set-and-unset-the-custom-field-value /